# GET with angularjs and spring

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am a beginner with spring and angular. I made a controller class in com.test.alex named Search. In my Search class i have this java code:

```
package com.siemens.cvc.isrules.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
public class Search {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getHelloWord", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getHelloWord(ModelMap model){
        String jsonData ="[{\"salut\":\"Hello Word\"}]";
        return jsonData;
    }

}
```

Then I have a UI with the following button:

```
<div class="input-group-addon" ng-click="doSearch();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></div>
```

When i press that button, i want to make a request to "/getHelloWord" (Search class) and alert the response.

This is the angularjs controller:

```
app.controller("search",function($scope,$http){
                    $scope.doSearch = function()
                    {
                        $http({
                            method : 'GET',
                            url : '/ISRulesTool/getHelloWord'
                        }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                            alert(data);
                        }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                            alert("Request Error");
                        });
                    };
});
```

And the problem i get is 404. 
"GET http://localhost:8080/ISRulesTool/getHelloWord 404 (Not Found)"

Where I need to make the request to get the response?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry the package is com.siemens.cvc.isrules.controller

Comment: Where did you declare the path /ISRulesTool ?

Comment: You could use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`, and lose the `@ResponseBody` on all your methods. But that's not the problem here. And note that, with AngularJS >= 1.4.4, the use of .success() and .error() is deprecated (see : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: did you check if your GET request is working with some REST client like RESTeasy or Postman ? Issue can be in your Spring layer. Put a debug point or a sysout in your `getHelloWorld()` and see if it's coming when you hit your GET request

Comment: Is this URL `http://localhost:8080/ISRulesTool/getHelloWord` working from any REST client in browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.
I need to add in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And create a new file dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.siemens.cvc.isrules.controller"  />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

And now works fine. Thx all for support.

Answer (score 1):

I think **"url"** that your mentioned in **$http** url params is wrong. Make sure that given url correct or not.

```
 app.controller("search",function($scope,$http){
                $scope.doSearch = function()
                {
                    $http({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : 'http://localhost:8080/getHelloWord'
                    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                        alert(data);
                    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                        alert("Request Error");
                    });
                };
```

});

Can you change the url like what i mentioned above.

By using **POSTMAN(RESTclient- Extension of chrome)** you can verify the GET request is working fine or not.

Comment: Nope. The URL used by OP is correct. He's just using a relative URL instead of an absolute URL like you mentioned here